# SQLite database gets larger after vacuum

Tags: sqlite

As part of refreshing some of the customer records in my sqlite database, I deleted a load of records and then imported some from an imported table. I then deleted the temp table and did a vacuum. The file was around 6mb before vacuuming and then 10mb after vacuuming. I did an integrity check and it seems ok. I did another test and if I don't vacuum, the file size is still about 6mb.

Am I doing something wrong?

(I've been doing the vacuum using a SQLite Manager. When using SQLiteSpy, however, it works properly. So it seems to be a problem with SQLite Manager. Might be of use to someone who has a similar problem)

Comment: Looks like a bug with SQLite Manager. Are other users of that tool experiencing the same thing?

Comment: Yes. It appears to be a problem with SQLite Manager. See above.

Comment: Yep. Just discovered that SQLite Manager balloons a 95Mb DB to 108Mb. Will definitely check out SQLiteSpy. Thanks.

Comment: `sqlite3.exe MyDatabase.sqlite VACUUM` works. NOTE: Don't make the mistake that I made and try to re-compact the blown up file - you'll see no change.

Comment: i encountered this problem using the SQLCipher command line tool - which in theory should be the same as the sqlite command line tool.  However in my case the size increase was only about 0.1%

Answer (score 6):

It's a bug with SQLite Manager. See my comments in the original post. Works when using another tool like SQLiteSpy.